# Lubuntu: VLC Won't Play DVD's

Tags: apt, lubuntu, video, vlc, dvd

I have downloaded and installed `lubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64` onto my old Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop, upgraded to run with 2GB RAM. This is a 64-bit machine with its original 80GB HD and is working fine in all other respects. I have also run a lens cleaner CD.

If I insert a DVD and attempt to open and then run it in VLC, the laptop and VLC recognize the DVD, but VLC then opens it and immediately terminates and disappears off the Desktop.

If I insert an audio CD and then run it, the laptop and VLC recognise and play the CD normally.

I have upgraded the VLC app', as bundled with Lubuntu, by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh (which didn't run)
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg && sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg.
```

However, the DVD just 'crashes' the VLC app' every time.

Any suggestions please?

Thank you.

Robin.

Term Window Output as Suggested:

```
rharwood@Inspiron1501:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[0000556f4139a580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Icon theme "elementary" not found.
Icon theme "breeze" not found.
[0000556f4143aca0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux: DVD Title: Casino Royale
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux: DVD Serial Number: 36368886
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux: DVD Title (Alternative): Casino Royale
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00ed0000. Regions: 02 05
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x05                                         
 
                                      
... 2000 char's removed ...                 
                 
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x05                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x06                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[00007f5354006a20] dvdnav demux error: Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:862 for cell_position[i].zero_1 : 0x04                                         
[0000556f4146d0f0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)                                                                            
[00007f53541efee0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[0000556f4146d0f0] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Not supported                                             
[0000556f4146d0f0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f53541efee0] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007f5388011a40] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r300_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f5388011a40] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error                                                                           
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
r300: driver missing
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 2
[00007f5388011a40] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: resource allocation failed                                                                    
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
r300: driver missing
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 2
[00007f5388011a40] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: resource allocation failed                                                                    
[00007f5388011a40] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
[00007f535407fe20] avcodec decoder: Using G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0 for hardware decoding
r300: Branches are not supported on R3xx/R4xx.
r300 FP: Cannot translate a shader. Using a dummy shader instead.
r300: Branches are not supported on R3xx/R4xx.
r300 FP: Cannot translate a shader. Using a dummy shader instead.
r300: Branches are not supported on R3xx/R4xx.
r300 FP: Cannot translate a shader. Using a dummy shader instead.
r300: Branches are not supported on R3xx/R4xx.
r300 FP: Cannot translate a shader. Using a dummy shader instead.
r300: Branches are not supported on R3xx/R4xx.
r300 FP: Cannot translate a shader. Using a dummy shader instead.
r300: Branches are not supported on R3xx/R4xx.
r300 FP: Cannot translate a shader. Using a dummy shader instead.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thanks, Robin.

Comment: Run the command `vlc` from terminal, and run the DVD from within the app. If it crashes, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1484788/edit) the question and paste the terminal output

Comment: Thank you Archisman, terminal output added to question as per your suggestion.

Comment: How did you install vlc? Is it the snap version or the deb version? Can you check if vlc is there in the output of `snap list`?

Comment: Output of snap list:

Comment: rharwood@Inspiron1501:~$ snap list
Name               Version          Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare               1.0              5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20             20230801         2015   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
firefox            116.0.2-1        2987   latest/stable/…  mozilla✓    -
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.efb213a    143    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-81-g442e511  1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.59.5           19457  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
rharwood@Inspiron1501:~$

Comment: Seems like it is not a snap package, and must be an apt package

Comment: Thank you Archisman, what does that mean? Can it be fixed? Cheers.

Comment: Can you please try `sudo apt remove vlc` and `sudo snap installl vlc`, and run `vlc` from the terminal, and post the new output, if any?

Comment: I grabbed a random DVD & tried it on a (*mostly new*) Lubuntu *jammy* box and alas it didn't play (*your issue maybe, my installed packages differ a little but I installed what you listed*). What @ArchismanPanigrahi suggested did fix the issue for me, or an alternative I regularly use is using `mpv` (`sudo apt install mpv`) to play the video. Both *snap* & *gnome media player* will use more RAM that default packaged `vlc`, but they do work (*my box had more RAM than yours; used RAM didn't exceed 1.1GB not counting cache on either but both used >2GB cached RAM*).  Thanks Archisman.

Comment: Hi Both,
Thank you both for your comments. I have tried the VLC snap install and also MPV. The VLC opens and runs the DVD, but only audio. MPV doesn't allow me to 'drop' the DVD into its main window, so I don't know how to run that. Maybe my machine doesn't have enough memory or perhaps I need an even lighter version of Ubuntu. It would be nice to be able to use the machine, given that it has a DVD read/writer. Thanks again.

Comment: I booted a Lubuntu *mantic* daily (*unreleased* 23.10) on `
lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb, i915)` and installed the packages you listed in line 1 & 4 (`ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `libdvd-pkg`) then inserted the movie DVD I used last time & it played. I also tried using 20.04 without issue, but I don't currently have 22.04 *daily* on thumb-drive to try it (*no time to write currently*).  You mention `vlc` snap working except for sound; did you look to fix no-sound via `pavucontrol-qt` as that's where I'd look for clues first.  Use @guiverc to ping someone (me in this example)

Comment: I note you have an extra "." or fullstop on line 4 of the commands you entered; that CHANGES THE PACKAGE NAME thus that command, if executed as you pasted in your question maybe your problem (*your provided command would be expected to return `dpkg-query: package 'libdvd-pkg.' is not installed and no information is available` or an error instead of required execution*)

Comment: Thanks Guiverc, I tried Lubuntu 23.10 and the DVD worked directly without having to install any extras(!!) Great except for 2 things: the picture was very digitised / grainy - which I am putting down to the RAM only being 2GB; and I could no longer run my installed wireless card, in-spite of the help given via:  'https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers';
It's a bit like squeezing dough - this one, but thanks for your help. Robin.